# Why do I get different inequalities from the same linear programming system?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex, simplex-method

This is from section 7.1 of Dasgupta's Algorithm book:[image: img]

I attempt to arrive at the optimal solution by using the existing inequalities.

$$x_2 \leq 300$$
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq 400$$
$$4x_2 + 12x_3 \leq 2400$$
$$\Rightarrow x_1 + 6x_2 + 13x_3 \leq 3100$$

However if I take another route, it gets me another value:

$$7x_1 + 7x_2 + 7x_3 \leq 2800$$
$$-(6x_1 \leq 1200)$$
$$2x_2 + 6x_3 \leq 1200$$
$$-(3x_2 \leq 900)$$
$$\Rightarrow x_1 + 6x_2 + 13x_3 \leq 1900$$

Suppose I do not know the optimal value is 3100, I'd be inclined to think that two acquired inequalities are both valid.  That means I should keep the the tighter bound of 1900, and ditch the first one.

What does all mean?  What have I done wrong?  Is this an indication that substitution is not the way to acquire the optimum in linear programming?

Comment: I am not able to tell what calculations you are doing based on your question. I think you need to add more details for people to be able to help you. We need 3 "active" planes (where equality holds) of which no 2 are parallel to select a point uniquely in 3D.

Comment: I am wondering what is the implication / meaning of having multiple inequalities for the same equation to be optimized.

Comment: The first set of calculations is correct and gives an upper-bound on the objective function. There is no reason that this upper bound in actually attained. The second set of calculations is not correct, You cannot sum $7x_1 + 7x_2 + 7x_3 \leq 2800$ and $-6x_1 \geq -1200$. Check how to combine inequalities together.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This must be the cause of the issue.